# How to count rows above the current one based on conditions in polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

Let's have a polars df:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
    'date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-07', '2022-01-17', '2022-03-02', '2022-06-05', '2022-06-07', '2022-07-02'],
    'col1': [4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1],
    'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 4],
    'col3': [2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1]
    }
)
```

| date | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2022-01-07 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2022-01-17 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 2022-03-02 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 2022-06-05 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 2022-06-07 | 4 | 3 | 4 |
| 2022-07-02 | 4 | 4 | 1 |

The df is sorted by date. I would like to create a column, that would give me a count of all the earlier rows (lower date) with all 3 columns having a value that is greater or equal to the value in the current row. Or in other words:

```
Count rows
    where row_index < current_row_index &
          col1[row_index] >= col1[current_row_index] &
          col2[row_index] >= col2[current_row_index] &
          col3[row_index] >= col3[current_row_index]
)
```

The result should look like this:

| date | col1 | col2 | col3 | ge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2022-01-07 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 2022-01-17 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 2022-03-02 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2022-06-05 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 2022-06-07 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 2022-07-02 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 |

I have tried various combinations of `shift`, `qe`, `over`, `when`, `cum_count` etc. but I have not been able to figure it out. I couldn't find a question similar enough to adopt its answer successfully either. Is there a way to achieve this using Polars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a [struct](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.struct.html#polars.struct) to put all the conditional logic inside [`.cumulative_eval()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cumulative_eval.html#polars.Expr.cumulative_eval)

```py
cols = "col1", "col2", "col3"

df.with_columns(ge =
   pl.struct(cols).cumulative_eval(
       pl.all_horizontal(
          pl.element().struct[col] >= pl.element().struct[col].last()
          for col in cols
       )
       .sum() - 1 # subtract 1 as we compare each row against itself
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (8, 5)
┌────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ date       ┆ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ ge  │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ date       ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ u32 │
╞════════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 4    ┆ 1    ┆ 2    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 4    ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-01-07 ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 4    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-01-17 ┆ 2    ┆ 4    ┆ 4    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-03-02 ┆ 2    ┆ 1    ┆ 3    ┆ 3   │
│ 2022-06-05 ┆ 3    ┆ 3    ┆ 2    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-06-07 ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 2    ┆ 3   │
│ 2022-07-02 ┆ 1    ┆ 4    ┆ 1    ┆ 1   │
└────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴─────┘
```

Comment: This is nice, i played a bit with struct with list of columbs inside of the eval but didn’t get it to the complete solution

Comment: I wonder - is there a nice pythonic way to reuse `pl.element().struct[col]` in the solution above somehow so we don't have to type it twice?

Comment: This is suuper nice!

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, the idea is to gather all the information you need via [`cumulative_eval`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.cumulative_eval.html) into lists, then explode resulting lists into rows and take into account only rows where all list values are true:

```py
import polars.selectors as cs

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        cs.starts_with('col').cumulative_eval(
            (pl.element() >= pl.element().last()).implode()
        ).name.prefix('_')
    )
    .explode(cs.starts_with('_col'))
    .with_columns(
        pl.all_horizontal(cs.starts_with('_col')).alias('ge')
    )
    .group_by('date','col1','col2','col3').agg(pl.col('ge').sum() - 1).sort('date')    
)

┌────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ date       ┆ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ ge  │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str        ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ u32 │
╞════════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 4    ┆ 1    ┆ 2    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 4    ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-01-07 ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 4    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-01-17 ┆ 2    ┆ 4    ┆ 4    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-03-02 ┆ 2    ┆ 1    ┆ 3    ┆ 3   │
│ 2022-06-05 ┆ 3    ┆ 3    ┆ 2    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-06-07 ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 2    ┆ 3   │
│ 2022-07-02 ┆ 1    ┆ 4    ┆ 1    ┆ 1   │
└────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴─────┘
```

You can also use `duckdb` to do that, thanks to [seamless integration with polars](https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/python/polars):

```py
import duckdb

duckdb.sql("""
    select
        d.*,
        (
            select count(*)
            from df as tt
            where
                tt.date < d.date and
                tt.col1 >= d.col1 and
                tt.col2 >= d.col2 and
                tt.col3 >= d.col3
        ) as ge
    from df as d
""").pl()

┌────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ date       ┆ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ ge  │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str        ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64 │
╞════════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 4    ┆ 1    ┆ 2    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 4    ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-01-07 ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 4    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-01-17 ┆ 2    ┆ 4    ┆ 4    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-03-02 ┆ 2    ┆ 1    ┆ 3    ┆ 3   │
│ 2022-06-05 ┆ 3    ┆ 3    ┆ 2    ┆ 0   │
│ 2022-06-07 ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 2    ┆ 3   │
│ 2022-07-02 ┆ 1    ┆ 4    ┆ 1    ┆ 1   │
└────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Thank you very much for both approaches, but especially for the one using polars selectors.