Create a conditional cumulative sum in Polars
Example dataframe:
testDf = pl.DataFrame({
    "Date1": ["2024-04-01", "2024-04-06", "2024-04-07", "2024-04-10", "2024-04-11"],
    "Date2": ["2024-04-04", "2024-04-07", "2024-04-09", "2024-04-10", "2024-04-15"],
    "Date3": ["2024-04-07", "2024-04-08", "2024-04-10", "2024-05-15", "2024-04-21"],
    'Value': [10, 15, -20, 5, 30]
}).with_columns(pl.col('Date1').cast(pl.Date),
                pl.col('Date2').cast(pl.Date),
                pl.col('Date3').cast(pl.Date)
                )
shape: (5, 4)
┌────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ Date1      ┆ Date2      ┆ Date3      ┆ Value │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2024-04-01 ┆ 2024-04-04 ┆ 2024-04-07 ┆ 10    │
│ 2024-04-06 ┆ 2024-04-07 ┆ 2024-04-08 ┆ 15    │
│ 2024-04-07 ┆ 2024-04-09 ┆ 2024-04-10 ┆ -20   │
│ 2024-04-10 ┆ 2024-04-10 ┆ 2024-05-15 ┆ 5     │
│ 2024-04-11 ┆ 2024-04-15 ┆ 2024-04-21 ┆ 30    │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────┘

What I would like to do is create a dataframe in which for each 'Date1' I would have a column of the cumulative sum of 'Value' where 'Date1' >= 'Date2' and 'Date1' <= 'Date3'.
So when 'Date1' ='2024-04-10' the sum should read -15, since the first 2 rows 'Date3' <= '2024-04-10' and the last row has 'Date2' = '2024-04-15' >= '2024-04-10'.
I tried this:
testDf.group_by(pl.col('Date1'))\
    .agg(pl.col('Value')\
        .filter((pl.col('Date1') >= pl.col('Date2')) & (pl.col('Date1') <= pl.col('Date3')))\
            .sum())
        shape: (5, 2)
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ Date1      ┆ Value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2024-04-11 ┆ 0     │
│ 2024-04-06 ┆ 0     │
│ 2024-04-07 ┆ 0     │
│ 2024-04-10 ┆ 5     │
│ 2024-04-01 ┆ 0     │
└────────────┴───────┘

But my desired result is this:
shape: (5, 2)
┌────────────┬─────┐
│ Date1      ┆ Sum │
│ ---        ┆ --- │
│ date       ┆ i64 │
╞════════════╪═════╡
│ 2024-04-01 ┆ 0   │
│ 2024-04-06 ┆ 10  │
│ 2024-04-07 ┆ 25  │
│ 2024-04-10 ┆ -15 │
│ 2024-04-11 ┆ 5   │
└────────────┴─────┘


Your approach does not work since the aggregation in group_by is computed separately for each group. Hence, the pl.DataFrame.filter is applied to the single-row groups defined by the column Date1.

I'll need to think about it a bit more to understand whether a solution relying purely on polars' native expression API is possible. However, here is a preliminary solution relying on the discouraged pl.Expr.map_elements.
(
    testDf
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("Date1")
        .map_elements(
            lambda x: \
                (
                    testDf
                    .filter(
                        pl.col("Date2") <= x,
                        pl.col("Date3") >= x,
                    )
                    .get_column("Value")
                    .sum()
                ),
            return_dtype=pl.Int64
        )
        .alias("Sum")
    )
)

shape: (5, 5)
┌────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────┬─────┐
│ Date1      ┆ Date2      ┆ Date3      ┆ Value ┆ Sum │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ date       ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64   ┆ i64 │
╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ 2024-04-01 ┆ 2024-04-04 ┆ 2024-04-07 ┆ 10    ┆ 0   │
│ 2024-04-06 ┆ 2024-04-07 ┆ 2024-04-08 ┆ 15    ┆ 10  │
│ 2024-04-07 ┆ 2024-04-09 ┆ 2024-04-10 ┆ -20   ┆ 25  │
│ 2024-04-10 ┆ 2024-04-10 ┆ 2024-05-15 ┆ 5     ┆ -15 │
│ 2024-04-11 ┆ 2024-04-15 ┆ 2024-04-21 ┆ 30    ┆ 5   │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────┴─────┘


You can use .cumulative_eval() i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77979270/ - it's still not ideal, but should be "faster" than .map_elements. I think "non-equi" joins are required to do this efficiently in Polars: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10068

This does work, though a bit slow. I've done similar operations using non equi join in R (dplyr has join_by(Date1 >= Date2, Date1 <= Date3) but couldnt find an equivalent feature in Polars.

@jqurious Does it really work with .cumulative_eval()? It crossed my mind, but I disregarded it as possible solution, as computing the sum for some values of date1 might require larger windows than defined by the current row.

Ah - perhaps I misunderstood the question - I thought they only wanted to look at "previous rows".

@jqurious I see - if this was the case, cumulative_eval() seems like the best approach indeed. Also, thanks for pointing out the discussion on "non-equi" joins. I'll keep an eye on it ^^

Not the most computationally inefficient, but perhaps the most generalizable
solution (assuming your 'Date1' columns is unique) will be to perform a cross
join reduction:
import polars as pl
from polars.selectors import starts_with
from polars import col

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "Date1": ["2024-04-01", "2024-04-06", "2024-04-07", "2024-04-10", "2024-04-11"],
    "Date2": ["2024-04-04", "2024-04-07", "2024-04-09", "2024-04-10", "2024-04-15"],
    "Date3": ["2024-04-07", "2024-04-08", "2024-04-10", "2024-05-15", "2024-04-21"],
    'Value': [10, 15, -20, 5, 30]
}).with_columns(starts_with('Date').cast(pl.Date))

print(
    df.join(df, on='Date1', how='cross')
    .filter(col('Date1').is_between('Date2_right', 'Date3_right'))
    .group_by('Date1').agg(Sum=col('Value_right').sum())
    .pipe(lambda d: df.join(d, on='Date1', how='outer'))
    .select(*df.columns, col('Sum').fill_null(0))
)
# shape: (5, 5)
# ┌────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────┬─────┐
# │ Date1      ┆ Date2      ┆ Date3      ┆ Value ┆ Sum │
# │ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
# │ date       ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64   ┆ i64 │
# ╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═════╡
# │ 2024-04-01 ┆ 2024-04-04 ┆ 2024-04-07 ┆ 10    ┆ 0   │
# │ 2024-04-06 ┆ 2024-04-07 ┆ 2024-04-08 ┆ 15    ┆ 10  │
# │ 2024-04-07 ┆ 2024-04-09 ┆ 2024-04-10 ┆ -20   ┆ 25  │
# │ 2024-04-10 ┆ 2024-04-10 ┆ 2024-05-15 ┆ 5     ┆ -15 │
# │ 2024-04-11 ┆ 2024-04-15 ┆ 2024-04-21 ┆ 30    ┆ 5   │
# └────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────┴─────┘

One can probably also go through duckdb for the inequality join as well.
import polars as pl
from polars.selectors import starts_with
from polars import col
import duckdb

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "Date1": ["2024-04-01", "2024-04-06", "2024-04-07", "2024-04-10", "2024-04-11"],
    "Date2": ["2024-04-04", "2024-04-07", "2024-04-09", "2024-04-10", "2024-04-15"],
    "Date3": ["2024-04-07", "2024-04-08", "2024-04-10", "2024-05-15", "2024-04-21"],
    'Value': [10, 15, -20, 5, 30]
}).with_columns(starts_with('Date').cast(pl.Date))

print(
    duckdb.sql("""
        with cte AS (
            select d1.Date1, sum(d2.Value) as Sum
            from df d1, df d2
            where d1.Date1 between d2.Date2 and d2.Date3
            group by d1.Date1
        )

        select df.*, coalesce(Sum, 0) as Sum
        from df
        left join cte on df.Date1=cte.Date1
        order by df.Date1
    """)
    .pl()
)
# shape: (5, 5)
# ┌────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────┬───────┐
# │ Date1      ┆ Date2      ┆ Date3      ┆ Value ┆ Sum   │
# │ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
# │ date       ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64   ┆ f64   │
# ╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
# │ 2024-04-01 ┆ 2024-04-04 ┆ 2024-04-07 ┆ 10    ┆ 0.0   │
# │ 2024-04-06 ┆ 2024-04-07 ┆ 2024-04-08 ┆ 15    ┆ 10.0  │
# │ 2024-04-07 ┆ 2024-04-09 ┆ 2024-04-10 ┆ -20   ┆ 25.0  │
# │ 2024-04-10 ┆ 2024-04-10 ┆ 2024-05-15 ┆ 5     ┆ -15.0 │
# │ 2024-04-11 ┆ 2024-04-15 ┆ 2024-04-21 ┆ 30    ┆ 5.0   │
# └────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────┴───────┘

